# Elegant way to convert list to hex string

Tags: python

I have a long list that looks like this:

```
[True, True, True, False, ... ]
```

Representing walls in a tile map. It isn't guaranteed to be a multiple of 4 long, but it doesn't matter if it gets padded at the end.

I'd like to convert this into a hex string, so for the above example it would start with E ...

I was hoping there was a nice elegant way to do this (using Python 2.7.3)!

Thanks.

EDITED

This is an example of a 9x9 map:

```
map = [True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, False, False, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, False, False, False, 
       False, True, True, True, 
       True, True, False, False, 
       False, False, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       False, False, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True, True, True, True, 
       True]# False, False, False padded
```

what I would like is to be able to

```
str = heximify(map)
print str
> FFF9F87C3F3FFFFFFFFF8
```

Comment: I think you mean byte string, right?

Comment: No, I actually want a string out at the end, something like eff5ac5664abe

Comment: Where do you want the padding (if the length isn't a multiple of 4)? And how exactly do you want it padded? Or, put a different way, can you show an example of your desired output for a input length of, say, 5?

Comment: answer marked as the correct one 16 hours ago, question put on hold as unclear 10 hours ago! Someone got it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Joining the one-liners club, by way of bit manipulation which seems more appropriate.

```
val = hex(reduce(lambda total, wall: total << 1 | wall, walls, 0))
```

This does the same as:

```
val = 0
for wall in walls:
    val <<= 1 # add one 0 bit at the "end"
    val |= wall # set this bit to 1 if wall is True, otherwise leave it at 0

val = hex(val) # get a hex string in the end
val = format(val, 'x') # or without the leading 0x if it's undesired
```

Comment: I think I might be being stupid or going very wrong, `print val` at the end of that gives me `0x1`?

Comment: @arshajii `tile` was a typo, it should have been `wall`. I edited the answer to fix this.

Comment: @arshajii Sorry, I used `tile` and `tiles` in my code then missed that one when matching it to the OP's naming. Thanks to Jon-Eric for the fix.

Comment: @MalphasWats The second example I wrote without testing for illustration purposes, I'll take a look at it. The first one should be correct though, if I understand your question  correctly.

Comment: @MalphasWats Right, I was missing the `<<=` there.

Comment: @MalphasWats That said, this doesn't do any padding, it will just map the bools to bits in a hopefully efficient fashion.

Comment: that's definitely closer, although `val = format(val, 'x')` gives me an unknown format code error, `val = str(val)[2:-1]` does the  job! Can pad it with `for i in range( 4 - (len(walls) % 4) ): walls.append(False)`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> walls = [True, True, True, False]
>>> hex(int(''.join([str(int(b)) for b in walls]), 2))
'0xe'
```

or (inspired by @millimoose's answer),

```
>>> hex(sum(b<<i for i,b in enumerate(reversed(walls))))
'0xe'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
walls = [True, True, True, False, ... ]
val = 0
for w in walls:
    val *= 16
    val += int(w)
val = hex(val)
```

or a dirty one-liner:

```
val = hex(sum(i*16**pow for i,pow in zip((int(w) for w in walls),range(len(walls))[::-1])))
```

Comment: I liked the look of this one (the top part) but val ends up as 0x1110 rather than E

Comment: @MalphasWats: I can't really debug much without an example to go on. Or perhaps I misunderstood your question

Comment: I updated my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> hex(int("".join(["%d"%s for s in [True,True,True,False]]),2))
'0xe'
```